# Software RAID 0 under Window 7 on 2 HDD only (including system drive) - is it possible

Tags: windows-7, raid, software-raid

I have two hard drives in my notebook. I cannot add third drive.

Is there a possibility to somehow set up software RAID 0 (striped) under Windows 7? My notebook does not support hardware RAID 0.

I am looking to increase the speed of reading data from my hard drives.

Comment: First of all the standard warning: RAID0 is not really RAID.

Now we got that out of the way: If you are looking to increase **reading** speed then RAID-1 will also work. 

If you still want to use a stripe, consider a regular /boot partition (that 100MB thing windows creates by default) and follow Luke answer below to create a striped volumes (e.g. C:, D:) for one or more partitions.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but you need to acknowledge that you will lose *all* your data if even just ONE drive dies.

Having said that...

As an Administrator, right-click on **Computer**, and select **Manage**. On the left side, open up **Disk Management**. Once that loads, you can right-click on the hard drive itself (not the part with the drive letter), and click '**Convert to Dynamic Disk**'. On your system drive, you'll need to reboot the machine.

[image]

After you have two dynamic disks, and some free space on both drives, you can create a volume, and choose to make it Striped. Right-click on the *Unallocated Space* of one drive, choose '**New Striped Volume**' and follow the wizard.

I have not seen the System Volume (where Windows is installed to) on a Software RAID 0, but that's not to say you can't do it. I haven't tried, so I cannot comment on that.